# Why is this vector of unit length?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

Given $A$ a symmetric positive definite real matrix and $V$ a non zero column vector define:

$B=V^\top A^{-1} V$ and since $A$ is p.d., $B>0$. Also, $A$ has a unique square-root $\sqrt{A}$. I purposely use a matrix notation for $B$ even though it's a scalar.

Define $W =  \sqrt{A}^{-1}V\sqrt{B}^{-1}$.

$$W^T W = \sqrt{B}^{-\top} V^\top \sqrt{A}^{-\top} \sqrt{A}^{-1}V\sqrt{B}^{-1} = \sqrt{B}^{-1}V^\top A^{-1} V \sqrt{B}^{-1} $$

Because $V^\top A^{-1} V\in\mathbb R$, $W^\top W = 1$.

I'm not sure, but I have the impression there is something more fundamental than $V^\top A^{-1}V$ and that it could be extended to $V$ being $n\times p$ matrices rather than a $n\times 1$ vector. Is there such an argument?

Comment: Are you sure $B^{-1}V (V^\top A^{-1} V) V^\top B^{-1}$ is $W^\top W$? It looks more like $W W^\top$ to me. Also, I think $W$ has length $b$.

Comment: @DavidK I corrected the question and changed it a bit.

Comment: You showed that $W^TW=\sqrt B B\sqrt B$, so isn't $W^TW=B^2\ne1$?

Comment: @Rahul Argh, typo again, sorry. $W=\sqrt{A}^{-1} V\sqrt{B}^{-1}$. Edited.

Comment: In that case, sure, as long as $V$ is an $n\times d$ matrix with rank $d$, then $B$ is an spd $d\times d$ matrix, and you can do exactly the same thing to obtain $W^TW=I_{d\times d}$. (I'm pretty sure, but I haven't worked it out in full.)

Comment: @Rahul I see, that's obvious in fact, I already wrote everything. But sdp in not enough for $\sqrt{B}^{-1}$ to exist, it has to be dp so $W$ have to be full rank I guess. Should I delete my question?

Comment: "spd" does mean "symmetric positive definite". Semidefinite would be "spsd".

Comment: This looks a lot better, and it works now, at least when $V$ is $n\times1$. I'm pretty sure it would work if $V$ is a matrix composed of orthogonal column vectors, not sure what happens otherwise. (The question is whether $B$ has an invertible square root.)